# Can I create a html and css text container from multiple rectangles?

Tags: html, css

As I have already stated in the title, I would like to know, if it is possible to make a text container that is made up of multiple rectangles in html and css.
For example, if I make a div and put the text in there, it will always be a single rectangle, but I want mine to be made up of two rectangles, through which the text can freely flow.

Here is an image of what I mean:

[image]

The darker part is the one, where I want text to be. It is supposed to be like a card with a title, a description and a call to action button, but I want the description to go over and then beside the button. I created this prototype with two separate rectangles, and I want to know if this is possible in html and css, and if it will count as one single container, so that I dont have to split the text into two separate parts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You may be able to achieve this effect just by using `float:right` on the rounded rectangle, allowing the text in the dark rectangle to flow around it as you describe, but honestly I feel this design is a poor choice and you'd be better off just moving the rounded rectangle down, below the dark one, keeping a more natural flow.

Comment: Do you have any representative HTML for us to - attempt - to work with? There's the possibilities of '[`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)', and '[`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)' to *emulate* the behaviour you describe, but there's no way to make a specific non-rectangular box as you describe (it can only be emulated).

Comment: You can use flexbox :)